# appsscript.json as a way to white list

Tags: google-apps-script

A very short and probably stupid question,

Is it possible to use the appsscript.json file to whitelist certain users? Or do I have to do it by some other means like through the GCP. I'm a very lazy programmer who is also paranoid of the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt that it's possible and it's probably not advisable.  If your paranoid of the internet the  why have you chosen google apps script?

Comment: Have the script file in a folder where you can manage the users who have acces. Otherwise somebody just changes the appscript.json

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

Comment: Thank you all, my questions have been answered. I'm not actually that paranoid, just wondered if it was possible and used humour to disguise the fact that I'm unsure.